# How to get checked value of checkbox on click a button from one component to other component in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 components one sidebar and home component.I have some checkboxes and a button in sidebar component,when I click that button I need to display checked checkbox value on home component. Already I am getting the alert but how to get the values,I am not able to get it.Here is the code below

### sidebarcomponent.html

```
<div class="header" *ngIf="router.url !== '/' && router.url !== '/login'">    
            <div class="citilist p-1">List of Cities</div>
            <ul class="p-2">
                <li  class="mb-3 p-1 border-bottom" *ngFor="let city of list;let i = index"><span class="mr-2"><input type="checkbox"></span><span>{{city.city}}</span></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="float-right mr-1 submitbtn"><button (click)="downloadClicked.emit(null)" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Submit</button></div>
</div>
```

### sidebarcomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { Router }  from "@angular/router";
import { CommonserviceService } from './../../utilities/services/commonservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() 
  downloadClicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  list: any[] = [{"city":"MOSCOW"},{"city":"TOKYO"},{"city":"LONDON"},{"city":"BRASILIA"},{"city":"NEW DELHI"},{"city":"KATHMANDU"},{"city":"PARIS"}];

  constructor(public router: Router,private commonserviceService: CommonserviceService){} 

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

### homecomponent.html

```
<div class="row m-0">
    <div class="col-sm-3 p-0 border border-bottom-0 maindiv">
        <app-sidebar (downloadClicked)="generarPDF()"></app-sidebar>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 p-0"><div class="citilist p-1">Output</div></div>
</div>
```

### homecomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  getListData: any;
  constructor(private commonserviceService: CommonserviceService) { }
  @ViewChild('content', { 'static': true}) content:ElementRef;
  name:string;

  ngOnInit() {
     
  }

  generarPDF() {
  this.name="hello";
  alert(this.name);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We're going to need to set a class level variable to track the selected value via the text box. We can do this by these updates.

**sidebarcomponent.html**

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="citilist p-1">List of Cities</div>
  <ul class="p-2">
    <li class="mb-3 p-1 border-bottom" *ngFor="let city of list;let i = index">
      <span class="mr-2">
        <!-- This allows us to set the class level variable of city to the correct city.  -->
        <input type="checkbox" (change)="citySelected(city.city)" />
      </span>
      <span>{{city.city}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="float-right mr-1 submitbtn">
    <button
      <!-- Here, we're going to emit that class level variable of city.  -->
      (click)="downloadClicked.emit(city)"
      class="btn btn-primary"
      type="button"
    >
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**sidebarcomponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { Router }  from "@angular/router";
import { CommonserviceService } from './../../utilities/services/commonservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() downloadClicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  list: any[] = [
    { city: "MOSCOW" },
    { city: "TOKYO" },
    { city: "LONDON" },
    { city: "BRASILIA" },
    { city: "NEW DELHI" },
    { city: "KATHMANDU" },
    { city: "PARIS" }
  ];

  city = "";

  constructor(
    public router: Router,
    private commonserviceService: CommonserviceService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  citySelected(city) {
    this.city = city;
  }
}
```

**homecomponent.html**

```html
<div class="row m-0">
  <div class="col-sm-3 p-0 border border-bottom-0 maindiv">
    <!-- Notice that we're passing in a $event value here. -->
    <app-test (downloadClicked)="generarPDF($event)"></app-test>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 p-0">
    <div class="citilist p-1">
      Output
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**homecomponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild("content", { static: true }) content: ElementRef;
  getListData: any;
  name: string;

  constructor(private commonserviceService: CommonserviceService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  generarPDF(event) {
    alert(event);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, here value is capturing on alert but, if I select multiple checkbox or uncheck the checkbox, its not working properly.

Comment: then you could change that city variable to an array and read the array

Comment: You could also remove from the array as well when you uncheck any one of the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I would collect all your checkboxes with ViewChildren in your sidebarcomponent. then filter only the checked and send the value to your parent component. (I just added the necessary and changed lines)

**sidebarcomponent.html**

```
<li *ngFor="let city of list;let i = index">
  <input #cbs type="checkbox" value="{{city.city}}">
  {{city.city}}
</li> 
<button (click)="send()">Submit</button>
```

**sidebarcomponent.ts**

```
   @ViewChildren('cbs') cbs;

   send() {
      // filter only checked element  
       const cbsChecked = this.cbs._results.filter(cb => {
         return cb.nativeElement.checked;
       });

       // send city name in defined list
       this.downloadClicked.emit(cbsChecked.map(cb => {
        return {city: cb.nativeElement.value};
       }));
     }
```

**homecomponent.ts**

```
generatePdf(cities) {
    console.log(cities); 
}
```

stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vniwxd

Comment: Thank  you, suppose I want to get those value as array of object like [{"city":"BRASILIA"},{"city":"NEW DELHI"}] , I am not getting how to do

Comment: ahh, i forgot. that's not much now. just return 
_return {city: cb.nativeElement.value}_
instead of the simple value. (I updated the code)

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo** in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uqkxat?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidebar%2Fsidebar.component.html)

**sidebar.html**

```
<button class="p-half" (click)="checkInputIsChecked()"> Send </button>
<ul class="p-2">
    <li class="mb-3 p-1 border-bottom" (click)="methodCall(cityName.checked, i)" 
       *ngFor="let city of list;let i = index">
       <span class="mr-2">
          <input #cityName [id] = "i" [checked]="city?.isChecked" 
                 [value]="city" type="checkbox">
       </span>
       <label [for]="i" >{{city.city}}</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**sidebar.ts**

```
list: any[] = [
               { "city":"MOSCOW" }, 
               { "city":"TOKYO" },
               { "city":"LONDON" },
               { "city":"BRASILIA" },
               { "city":"NEW DELHI" },
               { "city":"KATHMANDU" },
               { "city":"PARIS"}
              ];
checkedList;
@Output() downloadClicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() { 
}
methodCall(inn, inputIndex){
   this.list[inputIndex] = {...this.list[inputIndex], 'isChecked': !inn};
}
checkInputIsChecked(){
   this.checkedList = this.list.filter(item => item.isChecked === true);
   this.downloadClicked.emit(this.checkedList);
}
```

**Home.html**

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="sidebar p-1">
          <app-sidebar (downloadClicked) ="checkedInput($event)"></app-sidebar>
     </div>
     <div class="main p-1">
         <p>This is Home Main Content</p>
         <pre>
              {{inputChecked |json}}
         </pre>
     </div>
</div>
```

**home.ts**

```
inputChecked;
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
}
checkedInput(allCheckedInput){
   this.inputChecked = allCheckedInput;
}
```